# i18Next: use locale only for some languages and use language + location for rest

Tags: javascript, node.js, translation, i18next

I have a question for the i18next library. If I have these set of locales that are possible to be detected from the browser,

```
de
en-US
es
fr
it
ja
ko
pt-br
zh-cn
zh-tw
```

Is there a way to configure it where it respects the language only for some locales and not the other? for example, when it comes to `en-US`, I wish for the loaded language to be `en` so when I call the `.language` or `.languages` method, it will contain `en` instead of `en-US`. However, for the other locales that have a dash like `pt-br`, `zh-cn`, and `zh-tw`, they will remain untouched, (so NOT return just `zh`).

Is this possible?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, make use of the configuration options: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options

With the load option set to "all", it will first check for "en-US" and if not found, it will use "en"... and the `i18next.resolvedLanguage` value will be "en"

There are also other configuration options, like supportedLngs, or fallbackLng you could use to tune your use case.